# What sort of plot should I use to show possible paths from a start condition to an end condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I want to graphically show a map of all the routes someone can take from a start condition to an end condition. So for example what I have is

```
Nodes = [{name: 'start', label: 'Start'},
         {name: 'step_1', label: 'Step 1'},
         {name: 'step_2a', label: 'Step 2A'},
         {name: 'step_2b', label: 'Step 2B'},
         {name: 'step_3', label: 'Step 3'}];

Links = [{source: 'start', target: 'step_1'},
         {source: 'step_1', target: 'step_2a'},
         {source: 'step_1', target: 'step_2b'},
         {source: 'step_2a', target: 'step_3'},
         {source: 'step_2b', target: 'step_3'},];
```

At first I thought about using a gantt chart, since it is close to what I had in mind. But it seems to be wrong. Gantt charts are created for a completely different reason.

What would be the best type of chart and how can I create it, in order to show relations between the nodes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a simple flow chart would be a good option here.

Does it need to be built dynamically or can it be a static asset?

Comment: I get my data from a simple backend that I have created, and they can be dynamically changed from there. For that reason I think it should be dynamic. I am of curse able to read the data and create the object as I showed it in my question.

Comment: Actually thinking about it I do not want to build it dynamically. Using a repeater in my template would be more useful.